# Symfony http_basic authentication keeps asking for credentials

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, basic-authentication

I've tried using http_basic authentication for testing Symfony's Security package. But when I try to login with the admin/admin credentials and submit them, It keeps asking for them again.

This is the security.yml file

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: admin
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }]
```

And this is the main controller

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;


class MainController extends Controller {
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction() {
        return new Response('<html><body>Home page1!</body></html>');

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/admin", name="admin_homepage")
     */
    public function adminIndexAction() {
        return new Response('<html><body>Admin page1!</body></html>');
    }

}

?>
```

The server is live here: http://sym.soferonline.ro/admin

What could the problem be?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding this lines to the web/.htaccess seems to make it work.

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

this topic may help you [symfony2.3 http basic issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1813)